# can I wait the process to finish before starting reading lines from stdout?

Tags: java

suppose I start some process without reading the lines,

```
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands); 

    // startinf the process 
    Process process = pb.start();
```

can I wait until the process finish in order to read the lines in this way?

```
     runSafely(() -> process.waitFor());
    // for reading the ouput from stream 
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
     InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
    String s = null; 
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) 
    { 
        System.out.println(s); 
    }
```

my problem is that I am waiting forever.

Comment: Have you tried something like `process.waitFor(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`? That will wait for 20 seconds and then kill the process, I don't know if that's what you want. What does `runSafely()` exactly do?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes, there shouldn't be any issues with using `waitFor` before defining the streams of the process and starting processing them. But if you get stuck on waiting, there might be some other issues. You should double-check if the program you're trying to call isn't expecting anything on its input, also that the `commands` list is assembled correctly so the program doesn't hang up for some reason. You could also try adding a timeout. Finally, the external program might be finishing too quickly - this may cause `waitFor` to wait forever too.

Either way, it is known to be better to call `waitFor` AFTER capturing the streams you want to work with.

Also it is unclear why you would use the `waitFor` method inside a lambda expression, since that expression actually produces a private class inside itself, which looks very likely to cause problems.